# Sort after using Normalizr

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, normalizr

After using Normalizr I have an array like this:

```
comments : {
        byId : {
            "comment1" : {
                id : "comment1",
                author : "user2",
                date: "2017-05-09 05:30:00",
                comment : "....."
            },
            "comment2" : {
                id : "comment2",
                author : "user3",
                date: "2017-04-19 04:30:00",
                comment : "....."
            },
            "comment3" : {
                id : "comment3",
                author : "user3",
                date: "2017-05-19 05:40:00",
                comment : "....."
            },
            "comment4" : {
                id : "comment4",
                author : "user1",
                date: "2017-08-06 05:30:00",
                comment : "....."
            },
            "comment5" : {
                id : "comment5",
                author : "user3",
                date: "2017-07-01 07:30:00",
                comment : "....."
            },
        },
        allIds : ["comment1", "comment2", "comment3", "commment4", "comment5"]
    },
```

Now I have a button to change order between `id` or `date`. Then I need to change `allIds` (that retains sort order) to sort by date. The `allIds` should look like this:

```
allIds : ["comment2", "comment1", "comment3", "commment5", "comment4"] // sort by date
```

I do not know how this order could be made. I have made several unsuccessful  attempts with javascript `sort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply iterate the objects using `Object.keys()` and then sort `sort` it by the property date (parsed as `Date`):

```js
var comments = {
  byId: {
    "comment1": {
      id: "comment1",
      author: "user2",
      date: "2017-05-09 05:30:00",
      comment: ".....",
    },
    "comment2": {
      id: "comment2",
      author: "user3",
      date: "2017-04-19 04:30:00",
      comment: ".....",
    },
    "comment6": {
      id: "comment6",
      author: "user3",
      date: "2017-07-01 07:30:00",
      comment: ".....485",
    },
    "comment3": {
      id: "comment3",
      author: "user3",
      date: "2017-05-19 05:40:00",
      comment: ".....",
    },
    "comment4": {
      id: "comment4",
      author: "user1",
      date: "2017-08-06 05:30:00",
      comment: ".....",
    },
    "comment5": {
      id: "comment5",
      author: "user3",
      date: "2017-07-01 07:30:00",
      comment: ".....",
    },
  },
  allIds: ["comment1", "comment2", "comment3", "commment4", "comment5"]
};

var results = Object.keys(comments.byId).sort((s, a) => {
  const date1 = Date.parse(comments.byId[s].date);
  const date2 = Date.parse(comments.byId[a].date);
  
  if (date1 === date2) {
    return s.localeCompare(a);
  }
  
  return date1 - date2;
});

console.log(results);
```

References:

- [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

---

Note: *You forgot the commas after the `date` string. The commas after the `comment` string are not necessary.*

**Update**
Added another sort condition.

Comment: Works fine, but if it is the same time not is ordered by ID (comment1 and comment4), how can a second order be made?

Comment: @kurtko I've updated the answer and adding a condition for the sort function to provide some kind of *sort then by*.